# Print address for a Google Maps map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need to rearrange the code here, but I can't figure it out.  I'm trying to put the geocoded street address in the pop-up window.  I know it has something to do with variable access outside of functions but I'm just moving code around now and getting nowhere.

Please see the two comment lines in the code.

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.725685, -122.156830),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var places = <%= @locations.to_json.html_safe %>
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(places[i].lat, places[i].lng),
        map: map
    });


    var lat = (places[i].lat);
    var lng = (places[i].lng);

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode({
        'location': new google.maps.LatLng(places[i].lat, places[i].lng)
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {

            // THIS CONSOLE LOG WORKS.  IT PRINTS THE ADDRESS AS EXPECTED
            console.log(results[0].formatted_address);

        }
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {

        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(places[i].location_name + " <br /> " +
                places[i].location_description + " <br /> " +

                //HERE the variable "results" throws a Reference error, not defined
                results[0].formatted_address);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
```

Comment: Look up asynchronous requests and specifically how callbacks work with them.

Answer (score 1):

`results` is passed as a callback from the `geocoder.geocode()` function, yet you're referencing it in the `google.maps.event.addListener` function.

If you insist on your structure, put the `addListener` call in the `if ( status === 'OK' ) {` block.

The short answer is - you have a scope issue because you're trying to access one function's argument in another function.